# How to create custom http end point for Alexa skills with out using Amazon Lamda Function

Tags: node.js, node-modules, alexa-skills-kit

I have to create custom endpoint to build my alexa skill .
I want to develope the end point using node js technology. i have found alexa sdk from this this [link](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs)
But i am not getting the way for how can we write the code to build the custom end point for alexa skills
I already created alexa skills using amazon console. [amazon console link](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask)
I am stuck in developing the webservice for testing alexa skill. 
Can anybody give some example or guide to start coding in Node js for developing the custom end point for alexa.

Comment: You may find this [tutorial](codecademy.com/learn/learn-alexa) helpful. It will describe how you can create the webservice to handle requests from your alexa skill

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom endpoint. If you are using old console then you could see an option to select HTTP endpoint under configuration section as below,

[image]

If you are using new console then you could see it under EndPoint section as below,

[image]

Once selected HTTP you have to provide the API url.